# Application gets different date format

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, date-formatting

The server where I have deployed my ASP.NET application uses the date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. So it is expected that when accessing the application, the user should see the date in a calendar control formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy`.
But on some other machine it shows the date format as `dd-mm-yyyy`, and with this date format the SQL query crashes with a `datetime` conversion error.
Can you help me with this? Why does the date format change with the machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you provide more details on how do you receive the date from the user, I am suspecting that you are using java script component that generates the date format according to the logged in user

Comment: You can take date from the user and in server side  change it to what format you want then insert to database , so you can sure their is no conflict occur

Comment: As suggested by HossamBarakat it is most probably due to a client setting as your DatePicker control is most probably based on that. In 99% of the cases, if something is different on some computers but not on all, it is not related to the server

Answer (score 0):

it changes because of the culture set on the machine, but you can always format the date like this:

```
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", datevalue);
```